# Virtual column unknown when comparing lat lng

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to return only rows where the latitude and longitude being passed into the query, when compared to the latitude and longitude stored in the database, is a certain amount of miles apart.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    c.google_theatre_id 
    AS cinema_id,
    c.name 
    AS cinema_name,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
    cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
    cos( radians( longitude ) - 
    radians('-3.5247389') ) + 
    sin( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
    sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance
FROM
    google_cinemas c, app_users u
WHERE 
    distance < u.range
AND 
    u.id = 126
ORDER BY 
    distance
```

The query is designed to get the distance and then compare it to a column (`range`) in the `app_users` table.

When running the query, I'm getting an error of `distance` being an unknown column.

As this is a *virtual* column, is there a different way of comparing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try using `HAVING`. MySQL doesn't allow referencing alias columns in `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use HAVING instead of WHERE.. think of it this way WHERE is when you make an order at a restraunt and HAVING is picking stuff off of the plate when it comes to your table... you cannot reference an alias before the plate comes to your table only after it has been built

```
SELECT
    c.google_theatre_id AS cinema_id,
    c.name AS cinema_name,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
      cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
      cos( radians( longitude ) - 
      radians('-3.5247389') ) + 
      sin( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
      sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) 
    ) AS distance
FROM google_cinemas c, app_users u
WHERE u.id = 126
HAVING distance < u.range
ORDER BY distance
```

alternatively you can use it as a sub query which could be faster since HAVING re-evaluates the entire query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(   SELECT
        c.google_theatre_id AS cinema_id,
        c.name AS cinema_name,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
          cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
          cos( radians( longitude ) - 
          radians('-3.5247389') ) + 
          sin( radians('50.4521013') ) * 
          sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) 
        ) AS distance,
        u.range
    FROM google_cinemas c, app_users u
    WHERE u.id = 126
    ORDER BY distance
)t
WHERE distance < range
```

Comment: That is a weird, but nice, analogy. +1

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ haha thanks its a good way to explain it to people visually... that way they can understand how it works in a simplistic way :)